# navigation drawer items not clickable

Tags: android

Nothing happens when i click the items from my navigation drawer. I've tried putting the block of code to replace fragments in the `onCreate()` method just to test if my `FragmentTransaction` is working and they work well. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Here's my code for the navigation drawer that i learned from tutorials

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
                new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

                    }
                }
        );

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_budget:
                BudgetMain fragBudgetMain = new BudgetMain();
                ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragBudgetMain);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_expenses:
                Expenses fragExp = new Expenses();
                ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragExp);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_selfassessment:
                SelfAssessment fragSelf = new SelfAssessment();
                ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragSelf);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_mealcard:
                MealCard fragMeal = new MealCard();
                ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragMeal);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_ranking:
                Ranking fragRanking = new Ranking();
                ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragRanking);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient2">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my `app_bar_main.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My `drawer_view.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
                    android:title="Home"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_budget"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_budget"
                    android:title="Budget"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_expenses"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_expenses"
                    android:title="Expenses"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_mealcard"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_mealcard"
                    android:title="Meal Card"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_selfassessment"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_selfassessment"
                    android:title="Self-Assessment"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_ranking"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ranking"
                    android:title="Ranking"/>
        </group>


</menu>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: The drawer in a `<DrawerLayout>` should be listed last in order to be above the rest of the `View`s, and to receive touch events properly. Move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<include>`.

Comment: Great! It's now working perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one please:

```
mDrawerList.bringToFront();
mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
```

So you onCreate() method will look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
            new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

                }
            }
    );

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mDrawerList.bringToFront();
    mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: What is `mDrawerList`?